# How can I quickly visualize my computer's memory use?

Tags: macos, memory

I'd like to be able to see my memory usage as a pie chart in my mac's dock.

Comment: Here's the solution I found! Open the application, "Activity Monitor." In the dock, right-click its icon and under "Dock Icon" click "Show Memory Usage." In the icon's "Options" menu, click "Keep In Dock."

Comment: Please add a proper answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the application, "Activity Monitor." In the dock, right-click its icon and under "Dock Icon" click "Show Memory Usage." In the icon's "Options" menu, click "Keep In Dock."

Comment: Don't you want to comment on your answer to your question to make things clearer for you? :)